# Naive generalization of determinant from matrices to higher rank tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, tensor

Recall that using the Levi-Cevita symbol the determinant can be written as
$$\operatorname{det} A=\frac{1}{n!}\epsilon_{i_1\dots i_n}\epsilon_{j_1\dots j_n}A_{i_1j_1}\dots A_{i_nj_n}$$
Some computations that I do recently turned out to produce objects of the type

$$\epsilon_{i_1\dots i_n}\epsilon_{j_1\dots j_n}\epsilon_{k_1\dots k_n}\epsilon_{l_1\dots l_n}T_{i_1j_1k_1l_1}\dots T_{i_nj_nk_nl_n}$$
which look like a freshmen-style generalization of determinant to tensors. In my computations only even-rank tensors appear.

Is there a name for such things? Do they have any interesting properties?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213130
Hey! This might be exactly what you're looking for :)

Comment: @MoritzEissler Thanks for the link! The question there is indeed the same, but the answer just states the formula from my post without giving it a name of explaining why is that a good definition. Another suggestion was to check out hyperdeterminant, but as far as I can see it is different from my formula.

Comment: One interesting property is that this determinant is $0$ when the tensors have an odd number of indices.